# Using multiple redis databases in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

We're using redis for cache as well as for sessions. I'd like to be able to use seperate redis databases (same server, just different database) for each case, as well as being able to use the same server for production and pre-production. I know Redis allows you to define multiple databases on a single server (http://www.rediscookbook.org/multiple_databases.html), however I don't see how I can translate that to redis. The config (at least according to documentation http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/redis) doesn't mention anything about selecting a database.

Ideally, I'd have 4 databases, production-cache, production-sessions, pre-production-cache, pre-production-sessions (numbered 1-4 as redis doesn't allow you to name databases). Is this doable in Laravel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Here's an advice - don't use "multiple" (a.k.a numbered and shared) Redis databases (more on the reasons why at https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances). Use a dedicated Redis server (it's so lightweight that there's hardly any overhead) per purpose - it can save you many a headaches down the road.

Comment: Our host won't allow more than one instance per machine so we'd need to have 4 machines for this set-up which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: However, +1 for the info.

Comment: No problem - my pleasure. What hosting/provider are you with?